# Strange behaviour when drawing convex shape figure in SFML

Tags: c++, graphics, game-engine, sfml

I'm drawing a convex shape figure using SFML library:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
  RenderWindow window(VideoMode(400, 400), "SFML window");

  ConvexShape convex;

  convex.setPointCount(8);
  convex.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
  convex.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(180, 0));
  convex.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(180, 90));
  convex.setPoint(3, sf::Vector2f(100, 90));
  convex.setPoint(4, sf::Vector2f(100, 180));
  convex.setPoint(5, sf::Vector2f(30, 180));
  convex.setPoint(6, sf::Vector2f(30, 90));
  convex.setPoint(7, sf::Vector2f(0, 90));
  convex.setPosition(100, 100);

  while (window.isOpen())
  {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
      if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(convex);
    window.display();
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The points defined in clockwise order and everything is ok!
[convex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO25Q.png)

But when I change two coordinates a little bit I'm getting something that I really don't expect:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
  RenderWindow window(VideoMode(400, 400), "SFML window");

  ConvexShape convex;

  convex.setPointCount(8);
  convex.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
  convex.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(180, 0));
  convex.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(180, 90));
  convex.setPoint(3, sf::Vector2f(100, 90));
  convex.setPoint(4, sf::Vector2f(100, 200));   // CHANGED 180 to 200
  convex.setPoint(5, sf::Vector2f(30, 200));    // CHANGED 180 to 200
  convex.setPoint(6, sf::Vector2f(30, 90));
  convex.setPoint(7, sf::Vector2f(0, 90));
  convex.setPosition(50, 50);

  while (window.isOpen())
  {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
      if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(convex);
    window.display();
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm getting the following window:
[convex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9XwJ.png)

Why this situation take place?

Comment: You changed points of your shape and now it looks differently. Can you explain what you *did* expect to happen?

Comment: Your "convex" shape isn't convex, it's concave. SFML recommends you build concave shapes out of multiple convex shapes. SFML makes no guarantee about how it will render a concave "ConvexShape".

Answer (score 1):

These coordinates are related to the points in your Convex shape, you should use those only to change the format of the object. In order to move your entire object you should use this:

```cpp
convex.move(x Position, y Position);
```